# Making changes to instance template

Tags: google-compute-engine

I created an instance template. And used it to create an autoscaled instance group.

I wanted to know, what is the best way to make changes to this instance template so changes are pushed to all instances created from this image automatically.

Edit: To further explain my usecase. My application requires full access to shell so creating an instance template seems like the only way for me.
The docs say I cannot update my instance template. Is there a workaround for this? What is the standard way of tackling this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/recreate-instances) to recreate the existing VMs using the new or the same template whichever is set to your managed group:

```
$ gcloud compute instance-groups managed recreate-instances NAME --instances=INSTANCE
```

Another option is applying rolling updates using the [Instance Group Updater service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-managed-instance-groups). At the moment, as this service is an Alpha release, you may require to whitelist it in your project before using it.

Comment: Is there a plan to make the rolling update GA (it's been 2 years) ? This is a key feature of any auto-scaled environment. It is not clear from the docs if there will be service disruption if the recreate instances command is used.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: That does not really answer what I was asking, which is - when will the service be generally available and out of alpha?

Comment: Update: The rolling update feature is in beta now